# How do I add additional columns to Excel Power Query table that uses original columns as inputs for calculations?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I've built an excel table via power query that fetched data from an external API. I have the columns constructed the way I want from the original data request, but now I need additional columns outside of the api request added to the table. These columns need to multiply cells from original columns and output the result in the added columns.

Here is the table with the API data:
[image]

I need two more columns added to the right side with the heading of **calldelta** and **putdelta**

And in each column I need this formula calculated:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Call",E2)),100*D2*I2,"")`

or w/ the column header names

`=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Call",[callput])),100*[openinterest]*[delta],"")`

I've tried the "Add Custom Column" feature. I added the header name **calldelta** with the following formula:

`IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Call",[callput])),100*[openinterest]*[delta],"")`

and it spits out this formula with errors:

`= Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded greeks", "calldelta", each IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Call",[callput])),100*[openinterest]*[delta],""))`

I get `IF` errors and then more after that.

Just curious how to add custom columns to the end of this table. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In powerquery you would add column, custom column, with formula

```
= try if Text.Contains([callput],"Call") then [openinterest]*[delta]*100 else null otherwise null
```

syntax guide at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/power-query-m-function-reference